# Find closest parent in relation to (not just contained within) a context

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, ancestor

With the following html

```
<ul id="accordion">
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li><h3>title</h3></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li><h3>title</h3></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li><h3>title</h3></li>
        </ul>
    </li>       
</ul>
```

I have the outer ul stored in a variable

```
var acc = $("#accordion")[0]
```

**in the general case I am just passed the DOM element and can't necessarily specify a selector**

When a h3 is clicked I want to get the top level li that contains it. **In the general case there could be any kind of markup between the accordion ul and the element I wnat to fetch, and between the element to fetch and the h3**... but what I will have is a selector that lets me get to the element from the accordion using the ">" selector.

e.g. var items = $(">li", acc);

The trouble is that when I start from a clicked h3 ("this" inside the click handler) It's difficult to find the specific item.

```
$(this).closest(">li", acc);
```

returns an empty jQuery (maybe a bug? although it's difficult to define what ">" means in this instance, where the top level element is dynamic)

```
$(this).parents(">li")
```

doesn't allow a context to be set, so could potentially return too many elements

Is there a way to do what I want?

*edit: html now makes the problem clearer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(">li",acc).has(this)
```

works in general; setting a context on an initial jQuery appears to be the only place that startinga selector with ">" works in jQuery

Answer (score 2):

How about `$(h3).closest(".item");` ?  According to "closest" documentation, it will traverse the DOM up from current node until it finds a node that matches your selector.

Comment: This should be all that's necessary - the ">" qualifier is just wrong in that case, especially without anything to its left.

Comment: but if my markup was <div class="item"><p class="item"><h3>title</h3></p></div> this woudl return the p rather than the div (the markup I've used in the exmaple is a bit contrived, but a real world example where using > is useful is with nested ul and li elements)

Answer (score 1):

Go the other way, to guarantee the child relationship:

```
acc.children('li').has(this);
```

Comment: Nice solution, though it's a shame it traverses the dom outside of acc in order to find an element within acc

Comment: @wheresrhys, thanks for the prompt - I just thought of another way, see update.

Comment: even better! I think a problem in general though is that the selector *could* contain ">", but not necessarily (I'm writing a fairly general accordion plugin), so would need to also use a regex on the selector to check whether to use your method or closest(), and then if using your method, would need to further analyse the selector(e.g. ">li .target") to split off the part of it that actually is the descendant from the remainder of the selector... all work which should really be inside jQuery I reckon http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/8383#comment:1

Comment: unless, would find(">li") do the same as childern("li")?

Comment: Reading the specs a little more, it seems that > is only defined where there is a parent and child specified, which has lots of shortcomings when using some of jQuery's newer methods eg delegate()

Comment: @wheresrhys that's a good point about use with delegate. At the moment you may just have to resort to a filter function as it's the most flexible.

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(this).parents('li:last');
```

Comment: but this won't work when >li contains li elements as children